# Java Fatal Error with libawt.so IntRgbBicubicTransformHelper, don't know what it means

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat6, jvm-crash

We process images to extract various features from it. For it we resize the images upfront. Whenever we processed the images in an offline process with a single thread, we never faced any issue. But when we try to process multithreaded the JVM crashes inconsistently.

The biggest problem is on a same set of 10K images it processes the entire set a few (2-3) times before crashing and the more memory we give using -Xmx option the more likely hood of it crashing faster ... (For eg : 12 GB it might 30K images before crashing and with 16GB it crashes within 3-4 images) . Server is a 30GB n 8 Core machine ...

Monitoring "top" shows memory usage only at 20GB when crash happened though we had given -Xmx24g , so I assume it hasn't got anything to do with memory  ...

Be most appreciative if anyone can give me some insights of what the problem might be. I assume it's to do with threading, but I don't really know what :(

The Message :

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f61cd89e403, pid=31412, tid=140052355012352
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_67-b01) (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.65-b04 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libawt.so+0x78403]  IntRgbBicubicTransformHelper+0x143
```

============

```
---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f61640a3800):  JavaThread "http-8090-81" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=31607, stack(0x00007f607aced000,0x00007f607adee000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=2 (SEGV_ACCERR), si_addr=0x0000000586d22158

Registers:
RAX=0xfffffffffffffff0, RBX=0x0000000000000000, RCX=0x0000000000000000, RDX=0x0000000586d22158
RSP=0x00007f607ade6ae8, RBP=0x00007f607ade6b10, RSI=0x0000000000000010, RDI=0x0000000000000010
R8 =0x0000000000000000, R9 =0x00000000080c3592, R10=0x0000000000000001, R11=0x0000000000000000
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x0000000000000000, R14=0x00007f607ade8ce0, R15=0x080c3592b3333358
RIP=0x00007f61cd89e403, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010203, CSGSFS=0x000000000000e033, ERR=0x0000000000000004
TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00007f607ade6ae8)
0x00007f607ade6ae8:   00007f61cdad0db8 0000000000000000
0x00007f607ade6af8:   00007f607adeae50 00007f61640a39e8
0x00007f607ade6b08:   00007f60100d6fb0 00007f607adeaee0
0x00007f607ade6b18:   00007f61cd86af78 0000000000000000
0x00007f607ade6b28:   00007f607adeace0 00007f607adead80
0x00007f607ade6b38:   00007f61cdad0db8 00007f607adeae90
0x00007f607ade6b48:   00007f607adeaca0 00007f607adead40
0x00007f607ade6b58:   00007f607ade7130 00007f607ade8ce0
0x00007f607ade6b68:   00007f607adeae90 ffffff807adeae40
0x00007f607ade6b78:   00007f607adeaf38 00007f6000000000
0x00007f607ade6b88:   00007f607adeace0 00007f607adead80
0x00007f607ade6b98:   00007f607adeae20 00007f607adeaea8
0x00007f607ade6ba8:   00007f607adeaea0 00007f607adeae80
0x00007f607ade6bb8:   00007f607adeaf78 00000001c6666666
0x00007f607ade6bc8:   00007f60100d29a0 0000008000000000
0x00007f607ade6bd8:   00007f61cd89e2c0 00007f61cd869900
0x00007f607ade6be8:   419999999999999a 432997b8af8af8b0
0x00007f607ade6bf8:   00007f607ade6cd0 000000000ccccccc
0x00007f607ade6c08:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00007f607ade6c18:   001997b8af8af8b0 0000000006666666
0x00007f607ade6c28:   000ccbdc57c57c58 0000000006666666
0x00007f607ade6c38:   080c359333333358 0000000006666666
0x00007f607ade6c48:   080c359333333358 00000050f9999991
0x00007f607ade6c58:   000000461cccccbd 0000002800000000
0x00007f607ade6c68:   0000002800000028 ffffff8000000000
0x00007f607ade6c78:   00000000e3333333 0000004d0666665e
0x00007f607ade6c88:   0000005000000080 0e0bc4dc57c57c98
0x00007f607ade6c98:   00000003f999995a 0000008c00000000
0x00007f607ade6ca8:   0000005000000050 0000002800000000
0x00007f607ade6cb8:   0000000006666666 0df22d23a83a83e8
0x00007f607ade6cc8:   0000002800000000 0000008c00000000
0x00007f607ade6cd8:   0000005000000000 0000005000000000

Instructions: (pc=0x00007f61cd89e403)
0x00007f61cd89e3e3:   f6 44 23 65 c0 0f af 55 a4 44 01 e7 48 63 ff 48
0x00007f61cd89e3f3:   63 d2 48 03 53 10 43 8d 1c 03 48 63 db 48 01 c2
0x00007f61cd89e403:   8b 04 8a 0d 00 00 00 ff 41 89 06 42 8b 04 aa 0d
0x00007f61cd89e413:   00 00 00 ff 41 89 46 04 8b 04 9a 0d 00 00 00 ff

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0xfffffffffffffff0 is an unknown value
RBX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RCX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000586d22158 is an unallocated location in the heap
RSP=0x00007f607ade6ae8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f61640a3800
RBP=0x00007f607ade6b10 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f61640a3800
RSI=0x0000000000000010 is an unknown value
RDI=0x0000000000000010 is an unknown value
R8 =0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R9 =0x00000000080c3592 is an unknown value
R10=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
R11=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R14=0x00007f607ade8ce0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f61640a3800
R15=0x080c3592b3333358 is an unknown value



Stack: [0x00007f607aced000,0x00007f607adee000],  sp=0x00007f607ade6ae8,  free space=998k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libawt.so+0x78403]  IntRgbBicubicTransformHelper+0x143
C  [libawt.so+0x44f78]  Java_sun_java2d_loops_TransformHelper_Transform+0xe08
J 2084  sun.java2d.loops.TransformHelper.Transform(Lsun/java2d/loops/MaskBlit;Lsun/java2d/SurfaceData;Lsun/java2d/SurfaceData;Ljava/awt/Composite;Lsun/java2d/pipe/Region;Ljava/awt/geom/AffineTransform;IIIIIIIII[III)V (0 bytes) @ 0x00007f6241682ab3 [0x00007f62416828e0+0x1d3]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J 2084  sun.java2d.loops.TransformHelper.Transform(Lsun/java2d/loops/MaskBlit;Lsun/java2d/SurfaceData;Lsun/java2d/SurfaceData;Ljava/awt/Composite;Lsun/java2d/pipe/Region;Ljava/awt/geom/AffineTransform;IIIIIIIII[III)V (0 bytes) @ 0x00007f6241682a39 [0x00007f62416828e0+0x159]
J 1526 C2 sun.java2d.pipe.DrawImage.renderImageXform(Lsun/java2d/SunGraphics2D;Ljava/awt/Image;Ljava/awt/geom/AffineTransform;IIIIILjava/awt/Color;)V (773 bytes) @ 0x00007f624150bdd4 [0x00007f624150b560+0x874]
J 2059 C2 sun.java2d.pipe.ValidatePipe.scaleImage(Lsun/java2d/SunGraphics2D;Ljava/awt/Image;IIIILjava/awt/Color;Ljava/awt/image/ImageObserver;)Z (33 bytes) @ 0x00007f624168651c [0x00007f6241685ea0+0x67c]
J 2071 C2 *****************Image.resize(II)V (71 bytes) @ 0x00007f62416963e8 [0x00007f62416961c0+0x228]
```

..............

Comment: How are you processing the images? In general, you are only allowed to call AWT on one thread, and AWT is allowed to crash if you try to do anything else.

Comment: This is how we are resizing the images ... and then apply would custom feature extractions ...




    BufferedImage scaledImage = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    Graphics2D graphics2D = scaledImage.createGraphics();
    graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
    graphics2D.drawImage(image, 0, 0, w, h, x, y, x + w, y + h, null);
    graphics2D.dispose();